# selecting a random key and value pair from a hash

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to select a random key and value pair from a hash.  In my case it is a deck of cards.  I have been trying but failing to get the right answer

here is my code so far

```
deck = {
    "hearts" => [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"jack","queen","king","ace"],
    "diamonds" => [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"jack","queen","king","ace"],
    "spades" => [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"jack","queen","king","ace"],
    "clubs" => [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"jack","queen","king","ace"]
}

def create_deck(deck)
  hand = deck[deck.keys.sample]
  puts hand
  hand
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What answer do you get, and what answer do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reurn key and value pair change it to:

```
def create_deck(deck)
  key = deck.keys.sample
  {key: deck[key]}
end
```

Comment: for some reason when I try and print the value I am not getting anything back from the console

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
def create_deck(deck)
  cards = deck.keys.sample
  deck.each {|key, value| cards = [key, value] if cards == key}
end
# => ["clubs", [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]]
```

That should return a [key,value] array.